# schtasks - parameters. Microsoft documentation sucks

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, command-line-arguments

In Task scheduler library I have created a task. I need to perform the following.

1. enable / disable the task.

I used the following command:

```
  C:\Windows\system32>schtasks /Change /TN   "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Tasks\
  facebookdubsmash\facebookDubsmash.exe" /DISABLE
```

I got:

```
  ERROR: The specified task name  "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Tasks\facebookdub
 smash\facebookDubsmash.exe" does not exist in the system.
```

I tried just giving the task name alone.

C:\Windows\system32>schtasks /Change /TN   "facebook4dubsmash" /DISABLE

but I still get the same error.

Comment: How do you create this task? I mean, how do you name the task?

Comment: The task is already created manually. I just want to disable and enable it using the command prompt.

Comment: Yes but the TaskName is not the filename

Comment: I get the same error on giving the task name too,.

Comment: I have jus tried to create a simple task that lanches Notepad each hour. Named the Task as MyTaskName and I the command to disable it works as expected when used together with the task name. Something different should be at play

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SCHTASKS a new task is created with a command like this

```
SCHTASKS /Create /SC HOURLY /TN "MyTaskName" /TR "Notepad"
```

thus to change it to a disabled state you call

```
SCHTASKS /Change /TN "MyTaskName" /DISABLE
```

Just tried it with Win10 and works as expected. So if your code still doesn't work I suggest to try this code to see the output window and check if any problem is present in the command output

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = "cmd.exe";
psi.Arguments = "/K SCHTASKS.EXE /Change /TN \"myTaskName\" /DISABLE";
Process.Start(psi);
```

Comment: It worked. I Created a folder and in that folder I created the task. Now that I included the FolderName\TaskName and it worked.